# How can I make single particular KB article as publicly visible in Servicenow?

Tags: servicenow

How can I make  single particular KB article as publicly visible in Servicenow? I don't want to disturb other KB articles settings, I just need a single article to become public. How can I do that? Please help me out here

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a new Knowledge Base with 'Can Read' = 'Public' and create the article within that Knowledge Base.